# Trying to make a sample child theme of genesis?

Tags: wordpress, themes, genesis

Having a little bit of trouble trying to make a Genesis child theme. I don't want to touch the Genesis code so I am making a child theme of the Genesis Sample Theme. Is that overkill? This is my first time venturing into Wordpress and Genesis so I can use all the advice I can get!

I currently have one file (style.css) in my Child Theme of the Genesis Sample Theme. For Template should I reference genesis or genesis-sample?

Template: genesis

Also should I import the style.css from the genesis framework or the genesis sample theme?

@import "../genesis-sample/style.css";

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: so, you do not want to use the genesis-sample theme and want to create your own?

Answer (score 0):

Never do this because WordPress does not support child themes of child themes.

You can use a custom functionality plugin

or

Add custom coding at the end of your functions file.

Only Genesis is updated. Rarely are child themes of Genesis updated.